# Using subprocess() in with variable containing the DOS-cmd

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I not that good in programming and have a problem using the `subprocess()` command in Python.
My program creates the following string:

```
wsl ocrmypdf -sr -l deu "\mnt\z\dms\_inbox\Scan 2019-11-27 13.12.33.pdf" "z:\dms\_inbox\OCR_Scan 2019-11-27 13.12.33.pdf"
```

If I use this command in my Windows 10 DOSbox it is working without issues.

Now I want to start it with the following Python command:

```py
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).decode()
```

While `cmd` contains the above mentioned string.

The system returns something like `command wsl not found`.

What is wrong?

Update. The error message in wing is:
The error message in wing is:

> File "D:\DMS\MiniDMS.py", line 73, in    subprocess.run(cmd,
>   shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
>   universal_newlines=True).decode() File "C:\Python\Lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 512, in run   raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
>
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
>   ocrmypdf -sr -l deu \mnt\z\dms_inbox\Scan 2019-11-27 13.12.33.pdf
>   z:\dms_inbox\OCR_Scan 2019-11-27 13.12.33.pdf' returned non-zero exit
>   status 1.

I think there were some quotes missing in the string. So I changed it to

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe ocrmypdf -sr -l deu "\mnt\z\dms\_inbox\Scan 2019-11-27 13.12.33.pdf" "z:\dms\_inbox\OCR_Scan 2019-11-27 13.12.33.pdf"
```

the error output is now:

> Der Befehl "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe" ist entweder falsch
>   geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
>   which means that the command wsl.exe could not be found (even if it is there...)

Comment: Details matter. Include the entire message, not "something like" the error message.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if it can't find it then use `\full\path\to\wsl`

Comment: The error message is in german "something like" means I simply translated it. I'm using the wing IDE in debugging mode and can't find the keyword "traceback". "wsl" is the keyword for "Windows subsystem linux" and is usually used in a DOS box without any path. I'm not sure if it has a path or if it is a command like "dir"...

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behaviour:
wsl.exe is a 64bit application and therefore located in the real system32 folder. As my python installation is a 32bit application, it always refers to the SysWOW64 folder which does not contain the wsl.exe.

The way to solve it: I simply installed python as 64bit application, now it is working.

Comment: I know you've been away from the site for a while, but if you ever do stop back by, please self-accept your answer so this is closed-out.  Thanks!