# WSL with python subprocess

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to execute commands on WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) using python subprocess.

From the powershell and cmd the command `wsl -l` is working.

When I'm using python subprocess like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['wsl', '-l'], shell=True)
```

I'm getting the error that the command "wsl" is misspelled or not found. (I'm sorry for the german, but this is the original error message: `Der Befehl "wsl" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.`)

I also applied the fix listed in the troubleshooting section here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#troubleshooting-installation but it did not help.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Look at this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429146/using-subprocess-in-with-variable-containing-the-dos-cmd

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Python was installed in the 32 bit version, but the 64 bit version was needed.

Answer (score 1):

i'm kind of a newbie, but i could successfully run the following code for opening wsl from the windows prompt:

```
    subprocess.run(['wsl'], shell = True)
```

Comment: Hi, like answered in the referenced question and described in the comment under the question, it was an issue when Python is installed in the 32-bit version as WSL is a 64-bit executable.